# downloading large datasets using jdbc on redshift

Tags: jdbc, amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I'm using the Amazon Redshift JDBC driver to connect to Redshift on SQL Workbench/J.

I want to get my hands on a large dataset query result (several million rows).

WbExport seems to have the answer at first glance (http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/command-export.html).

However, it seems to want to load the entire result set into memory before trying to export it into a file, gives me a memory warning and aborts the query on me without even creating the output file, so this approach seems to not work.

Is there a better approach that doesn't involve ditching SQL Workbench and the JDBC connection? If not, what's a suggested viable alternative that minimizes the amount of new tools or access necessary?

Comment: For a huge dataset, I would look at whether the database itself (this case Amazon Redshift) could provide the solution.  I am not familiar with Redshift per se, but I found a link about unloading data that may prove useful.

Comment: I don't know about the Redshift driver, but for Postgres, you need to configure cursor based retrieval (as mentioned in the section "Memory usage and WbExport" of your link): https://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/dbms-problems.html#pg-problems

Comment: I can see the problem is that it's trying to load the entire thing into memory - as evidenced by watching the memory usage of the workbench process skyrocket in Task Manager as it runs. One workaround has been to load up 'sqlworkbench.cmd', it seems to allocate max memory usage to available memory divided by two. I changed to divided by 1.2, and my query worked.. Not a solution though, just a workaround for this specific case because I happen to have enough available in my machine.

Comment: Did you try to set the `BlockingRowsMode` option: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-options.html

Answer (score 0):

Strongly recommend that you **do not** try to retrieve millions of rows from Redshift as a query result. This is very inefficient and it will slow down your cluster while it runs.

Instead use an `UNLOAD` query to extract the data to S3 in parallel. `UNLOAD` will be 100x-1000x faster. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

Answer (score 0):

Though not very effecient for redshift, but if you really need it, you should be able to set fetchsize for workbench- http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/profiles.html.

Aws redshift documentation regarding same- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/queries-troubleshooting.html#set-the-JDBC-fetch-size-parameter

Answer (score -1):

You can use fastest approach.
1.Unload data to S3. 
2.Then download data from S3.